# dnf: how to completely remove package (.rpmsave, .rpmnew files etc.)

Tags: yum, rpm, dnf

Is there a way to fully remove package with `dnf`? Normally `dnf remove package-name` will keep configuration files, which were modified locally, as for example /etc/my-package/config-file.rpmsave or similar. Does `dnf` have a command-line option to completely remove stale/saved files of the package?

Comment: Configuration files that are renamed (`.rpmsave` or `.rpmnew`) are not tracked by dnf. The best you could is get a list of configuration files from a given package (`rpm -qlc <packagename>`), and then iterate over them looking for `<filename>.rpmsave` and `<filename>.rpmnew` (before deleting the package).

Answer (score 0):

Not with DNF. But you can

```
rpmconf --clean
```